# Default Textbox Colors in Powerpoint 2007

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2007

How do i change defalut colors for a new Textbox in PowerPoint 2007? I am using a custom themed presentation template that someone gave me and every time I create a new text box it is white text on white background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got a text box with the colours you want, right click on it and select "Set as Default Shape". New shapes should then use the same colours. Does that help?